# How to make this plot?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

Found this beautiful plot here

[image: plot]

but I don't know how to write the code for the *Mathematica* plot... I found the parameterization

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}[2+\cos(u)]\cos(v)\\ [2 + \cos(u + 2 \pi / 3)] \cos(v + 2 \pi / 3) \\  [2 + {\rm{sign}}(F(u)) \sqrt{|F(u)|}] {\rm{sign}}(F(v)) \sqrt{|F(v)|} \end{pmatrix}$

where $F(s) = 1 - \cos(s)^2 - \cos(s + 2 \pi / 3)^2$ and $0\le u\le 2\pi$, $0\le v\le 2\pi$

It should be possible, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Would be nice if someone could help me.

---

With your help I've come this far
[image]

The Code I'm currently woriking with is

```
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[u]) Cos[v], (2 + Cos[u + (2 \[Pi])/3]) Cos[
v + (2 \[Pi])/3], (2 + Sign[F[u]]) Sqrt[Abs[F[u]]]
Sign[F[v]] Sqrt[Abs[F[v]]]}, {u, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {v, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
Mesh -> All, MeshFunctions -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 200, 
Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Exclusions -> None, 
PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
PlotTheme -> "Simple"]
```

The Problem is, that I want the mesh to be coloured and the space between the lines to be empty. But that's not really working..

Has anyone a idea how to implement that?

Thanks

Comment: Use `ParametricPlot3D`.

Comment: What's the source? Also, please give the equations in Mathematica syntax.

Answer (score 6):

directly drawing grid lines:

```
F[u_] = 1 - Cos[u]^2 - Cos[u + 2/3 Pi]^2;
g[u_, v_] = {
   (2 + Cos[u]) Cos[v],
   (2 + Cos[u + (2 \[Pi])/3]) Cos[v + (2 \[Pi])/3],
   (2 + Sign[F[u]]) Sqrt[Abs[F[u]]] Sign[F[v]] Sqrt[Abs[F[v]]]};
Graphics3D[
 {Table[Line[#, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ (#[[All, 1]]/3 /Pi))] &@ 
    Table[ g[u, v] , {u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}], {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}],
  Table[Line[#, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ (#[[All, 1]]/3 /Pi))] &@ 
    Table[ g[u, v] , {v, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}], {u, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/40}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: One could use `ParametricPlot3D[]` with an appropriate `ColorFunction`, too.

Answer (score 4):

Too long for a comment.

It is certainly very different from your plot, but this is what I got using your parametrisation and `ParametricPlot3D` as suggested by Szabolcs and `Exclusions->None` as suggested by J.M.:

[image]

```
F[s_] = 1 - Cos[s]^2 - Cos[s + 2 Pi/3]^2;
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[u]) Cos[v], (2 + Cos[u + 2 Pi/3]) Cos[
    v + 2 Pi/3], (2 + Sign[F[u]])*
   Sqrt[Abs[F[u]]] Sign[F[v]] Sqrt[Abs[F[v]]]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 
  2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 200, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

For fun, we can add the following options taken from the documentation of `ParametricPlot3D`:

```
Mesh -> 100, MeshFunctions -> {#5 - 3 #4 &}, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Hue[u/(2 Pi)]], 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False,  MeshShading -> {Black, Automatic, Automatic},
MeshStyle -> None]
```

[image]

You might get further help by being more specific about what issues you are facing.

Comment: You might want to add `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, edited.